# selenium dynamic values

Tags: selenium

how to capture dynamic values of button using selenium scripts?

Comment: Can you provide more information? A sample of the HTML would be useful with details of what you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find an element on a page that is dynamically generated, you can use XPath or CSS selectors to find that element. The selector needs to be general enough to capture all possibilities of the dynamic element while being specific enough to not match another element on the page. This usually works best by assigning an ID to the button when possible.

If you're referring to checking the contents/properties of the button with Selenium, that should be fairly straightforward. Once you have the correct selector, you should be able to access the inner HTML (or any other information you want about that element, really).

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium getText and getValue to extract text from a button. If only button text is dynamic and button itself is static then its location/UI locator can be easily fetched also

Answer (score 0):

To capture dynamic values the best way which I use is "xpath".
The reason behind that is whenever you are going for a dynamic element then you need to find out that element's parent html path up to that element.

Example :

Suppose we have a html source like :

```
 <div class="sfibbbc">
        <div id="sbtc" class="sbtc">
            <div class="sbibtd">
                <div id="sfdiv" class="sbibod ">
                    <div class="gstl_0 sbib_a" style="height: 38px;">
                        <div id="gs_st0" class="gsst_b sbib_c" style="line-height: 38px;" dir="ltr">
                            <a class="gsst_a" href="javascript:void(0)" aria-label="Search by image">
                                <span id="gs_si0">
                                    <span id="qbi" class="gsst_e"></span>
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Here in this code if we need find out {span id="qbi" class="gsst_e" /span} 
and id is dynamic which means it got changed whenever you log in to that page.

To achieve that we need to derive xpath like ->

//div[@id='gs_st0']//a//span//span[@class='gsst_e']

SO that each time if it will generate a new ID then also WebDriver can find the element through its parent path.